# Python GTK - AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'Stack'

Tags: python, gtk

I'm following [the  Python GTK tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/) to learn to make simple apps on Ubuntu. While the first few snippets ran without issues, I get to the [Stack and StackSwitcher](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout.html#stack-and-stackswitcher) part and it begins with trouble. Specifically:

```
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'Stack'
```

And I'm out of options here, since I don't know what's happening. I have GTK3 installed, as well as Python 2.7.4 and 3.3.1 but I think I'm importing an older GTK version however

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk

print str(Gtk.get_major_version()) + "." + str(Gtk.get_minor_version()) + "." + str(Gtk.get_micro_version())
```

Outputs

```
3.6.4
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, am I missing installing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [GTK+ documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack) the GtkStack widget was added in GTK+ 3.10, while PyGObject is reporting that the version of GTK+ you have installed is 3.6.4

You will need to install GTK+ 3.10 or higher to get access to this widget.